# Is this sentence in passive form? ナツキの目が一瞬こちらに向けられた

Tags: sentence

**>ナツキの目が一瞬こちらに向けられた**

Natsuki's eyes turned to me for a moment

1. Is 向けられる here used as passive?
2. Is 目が向けられる a phrase?

Trying to search for the meaning of 目が向けられる only 目を向ける shows up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a passive sentence. 向けられた is the past-passive form of 向ける, and 向ける is a simple transitive verb. 目を向ける is a set phrase.

> ナツキの目がこちらに向けられた。
> Natsuki's eyes were turned to me.
>
> ナツキの目がこちらに向いた。
> Natsuki's eyes turned to me.